# How to access the dictionary key values inside a list which is a column in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a data frame with multiple columns like **key_id, name, score, outcome & category_reasons**.
The category_reasons columns holds value as below for each of the key_id. For some of the key_id it will have only one category & value for other it will have multiple category & value as below
How can I create a new column such that it includes only the category values for the **category** field as a list in a new column[Sample Input/Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roeoM.png) category_reasons1.
Please see the embedded like to view the Sample Input & Output required.
Could anyone help me on how to resolve this issue?

```
[{'category': 'A', 'value': ['12']},
 {'category': 'B', 'value': ['13a']},
 {'category': 'C', 'value': ['14c']}]
```

[Sample Input/output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roeoM.png)

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you tried anything? Please provide a [mcve]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score -1):

**To get keys:**

You can just create a new column as :

```
df["new_category_reasons"] = [','.join(l.keys()) for l in [OrderedDict(d) for  d in df["category_reasons"]]]
```

or if you don't want to create a new column , just assign the existing column :

```
df["category_reasons"] = [','.join(l.keys()) for l in [OrderedDict(d) for  d in df["category_reasons"]]]
```

- Get OrderedDict from each dictionary in the column 'category_reasons' and join the keys with "," to get the comma separated string of keys.
- You need OrderedDict in order to preserve the order of keys and then get the first key. Otherwise you may get `value` as the first key in `d.keys()` sometimes as you know `keys()` is a set which is unordered by nature.

Example :

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
data = [[1,[{'categoryA': 'A', 'value': ['12']},
 {'categoryB': 'B', 'value': ['13a']},
 {'categoryC': 'C', 'value': ['14c']}]], [2,[{'categoryA':'A', 'value':['12']}, {'categoryB':'B', 'value':['13a']}]]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["key_id","category_reasons"])
from collections import OrderedDict
df['new_category_reasons'] = [','.join(l.keys()) for l in [OrderedDict(d) for  d in df["category_reasons"]]]
```

Output:

```
key_id  category_reasons    new_category_reasons
0   1   [{'categoryA': 'A', 'value': ['12']}, {'catego...   categoryA,categoryB,categoryC
1   2   [{'categoryA': 'A', 'value': ['12']}, {'catego...   categoryA,categoryB
```

**To get values:**

To get the values e.g. [A,B,C] instead, you could do the following:

- You could define a function to extract values from the list of dictionaries that is present in each 'category_reason' like:

```
    def get_category_values(category_list):
        l = []
        for d in category_list:
            od = OrderedDict(d)
            l.append(od[list(od.keys())[0]])
        return l
```

- Use this function with a list comprehension to get the new column 'category_reason1' like:

```
    df['category_reason1'] = [get_category_values(category_list) for category_list in df['category_reasons']]
```

Output :

```
key_id  category_reasons    category_reason1
0   1   [{'categoryA': 'A', 'value': ['12']}, {'catego...   [A, B, C]
1   2   [{'categoryA': 'A', 'value': ['12']}, {'catego...   [A, B]
```

Comment: How can I do to retrieve the values of the category like [A,B,C] for the first key Id. Like this for the first record. Could you please help me on this                                                                                                                        
key_id name score outcome category_reasons1
1         AA         0.12         High         [A,B,C]

Comment: I m not sure I got your question, looks like a new requirement, please update your question with this.

Comment: I have updated the same . Could you please check the sample attachment . I have updated the output required

Comment: @Amrit I updated the answer to get the values instead of keys.

Comment: It is working now.  Thanks you so much @SomeDude. I am trying to handle None values as well now. If the category_reason consists of the value 'None' it should return 'None' in the new category_reasons1 as well.

Comment: @Amrit, if you think it answers your question you should consider upvoting and accepting it. BTW the def get_category_values should handle None values as well.

Comment: Sure . I will do that now. It was not handling the None values so I just included a if condition inside the function to check if the category_reasons are None and returned None. So now it is working as well. Thanks for you help and suggestions